# Setting CSS styling based on value in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to set the CSS style based on a value for the HTML element, how would i do?

.JSP file:

```
   <div style="margin-left:-14%;margin-top:-2.4%" >
       **<bean:write name="messageFormBean" property="messageVO.messageFormat"/>**
   </div>
```

For now I have set the styling to `margin-left: -14%;`, but
if the value for the highlighted statement (bold) is "A", then the style should be `margin-left:-14%;`, if it is "B" then it should be `margin-left:-3%;`.

How would I use conditional operator and set the styling accordingly?

Comment: Consider using custom css properties, also known as css variables. https://davidwalsh.name/css-variables-javascript

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using JS you could add a `data` attribute on the `div` element with the value you also print inside, e.g.

```
<div data-letter="<bean:write ... />"> <!-- or whatever it takes to print the same value here -->
   <bean:write name="messageFormBean" property="messageVO.messageFormat"/>
</div>
```

and use all the necessary CSS *attribute* selectors to set all the properties you need

```
[data-letter="A"] { margin: -2.4% 0 0 -14% }
[data-letter="B"] { margin: -2.4% 0 0 -3% }
...

[data-letter="Z"] { margin: ... }
```

Benefit of this approach: no unnecessary use of JS, no CSS-in-JS and no inline style.